# List files in Azure data lake storage using wild cards in Rest API

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-files

Can we use wild cards in Azure data lake storage Gen 2 file listing Rest API?

According to this document :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/datalakestoragegen2/path/list

If I make a Rest call like this, it gives all the files in **artists** folder:
https://storageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/files?directory=files/artists&resource=filesystem&recursive=false

But I want only few files which match my search key word, so is there a way to do a wild card search ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, the Azure data lake gen2 [Path - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/datalakestoragegen2/path/list) does not support wild card search.

But if you enroll in [the public preview of multi-protocol access on Data Lake Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-multi-protocol-access), then blob APIs and Data Lake Storage Gen2 APIs can operate on the same data. So that you can take use of the [list blobs api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-blobs) for your ADLS GEN2, then you can use the [prefix url parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-blobs#uri-parameters) to filter out some files. Note that this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-known-issues#issues-and-limitations-with-using-blob-apis-on-accounts-that-have-a-hierarchical-namespace) contains the limitation of blob api for ADLS GEN2.

Also, you can submit a feedback about this api on the [Data Lake Feedback form](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/327234-data-lake)